# com.android.support versions do not match the exact same version

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.and.facebook"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.20.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

After I put the facebook sdk into the dependencies, it gives me this compile error.
[image]
where is com.android.support.cardview-v7 25.0.0??? and how do I update this to 25.2.0?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line:
`compile 'com.android.support.cardview-v7:25.2.0'`

Comment: Thanks. While this is indeed the right answer, just adding this alone did not work for me. I then realized this was because facebook library used cardview internally and this was conflicting with my own import. I solved it by adding an exclude group to the facebook gradle import.
`exclude group: ‘com.android.support'`